# Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a method within my repository which queries two separate join tables. I am trying to combine the two IQueryables before converting them into Lists but I am receiving the above error message in the console.

Here is the method within the repository:

```
public async Task<PagedList<EventDto>> GetUserOrganisedEvents(EventParams eventParams)
{
    var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(eventParams.username);

    var organisedEventsquery = _context.UserEvents.AsQueryable();

    var organisedEvents = organisedEventsquery.Where(events => events.OrganiserId == user.Id);

    var AttendedEventsquery = _context.EventUsers.AsQueryable();

    var AttendedEvents = AttendedEventsquery.Where(events => events.AttendeeId == user.Id);

    var organisedEventsList = organisedEvents.Select(organisedEvent => new EventDto
    {
        Name = organisedEvent.Event.Name,
        Id = organisedEvent.EventId,
        Date = organisedEvent.Event.Date,
        Location = organisedEvent.Event.Location,
        MainPhotoUrl = organisedEvent.Event.MainPhotoUrl,
        Creator = _mapper.Map<MemberDto>(organisedEvent.Event.Creator),
        Organisers = _mapper.Map<ICollection<MemberDto>>(organisedEvent.Event.Organisers),
        Attendees = _mapper.Map<ICollection<MemberDto>>(organisedEvent.Event.Attendees)
    });

    var AttendedEventsList = AttendedEvents.Select(AttendedEvent => new EventDto
    {
        Name = AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.Name,
        Id = AttendedEvent.AttendingEventId,
        Date = AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.Date,
        Location = AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.Location,
        MainPhotoUrl = AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.MainPhotoUrl,
        Creator = _mapper.Map<MemberDto>(AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.Creator),
        Organisers = _mapper.Map<ICollection<MemberDto>>(AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.Organisers),
        Attendees = _mapper.Map<ICollection<MemberDto>>(AttendedEvent.AttendingEvent.Attendees)
    });

   var events = organisedEventsList.Concat(AttendedEventsList);

   return await PagedList<EventDto>.CreateAsync(events, eventParams.PageNumber, eventParams.PageSize);
}
```

Here is the `CreateAsync` method:

```
public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize) 
{  
    var count = await source.CountAsync(); 

    var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync(); 

    return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);   
}
```

Comment: In your query, you have some instruction that EF Core cannot interpret. I bet on `_mapper.Map`.

Comment: But if I remove one of the select statements and just pass in 1 IQueryable without joining the other one, it works?

Comment: The error message sounds like coming from `entity-framework-core`. If yes, consider changing the tag and providing the EF Core version. Although it's unlikely to get resolution, even if you remove `_mapper.Map` methods and replace `Select` with `ProjectTo`, because looks like merging queries involving sub collections is not supported even in the latest EF Core version.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error too.
Much simpler query.

```
        var query1 = _context.Set<TableA>()
        .Select(x => NewMethod(x));

    var query2 = _context.Set<TableB>()
        .Select(x => NewMethod1(x));

private static ViewModel NewMethod1(TableA x)
{
    return new ViewModel()
    {
        Number = x.Number,
        Date = x.Date
    };
}

private static ViewModel NewMethod(TableB x)
{
    return new SalesLedgerRecord()
    {
        Number = x.Number,
        Date = x.Date
    };
}
```

The shown code above will fail with the error message in the subject if I union the results:
var query = query1.Union(query2)
.OrderBy(OrderBy).AsNoTracking();

However, if I remove the two private static functions to have:

```
    var query = _context.Set<TableA>()
        .Select(x =>
        new ViewModel()
        {
            Number = x.Number,
            Date = x.Date
        };
```

All seems to be working ok.
Also, all works if I leave 'NewMethodX' but remove the union.
Not sure what change extracting to private static changes but it does changes something.